# On loading Image, getImageData delivers some zeros

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm loading a PNG and try to check, whether it is fully opaque, meaning alpha channel is near 100% over the whole image. Therefore, I use the canvas and 2D-Context to get the pixel data and loop through it checking the alpha value.

To my surprise i get whole areas of zeros (RGBA = [0000]) where it obviously shouldn't.

*Browser in focus: chrome 50.0.2661.87*

Here is my code, it is embedded in a *ThreeJS* environment:

```
var imageData = zipHandler.zip.file(src); // binary image data

var texture = new THREE.Texture();

var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    texture.imageHasTransparency = false; // extend THREEJS Texture by a flag

    if (img.src.substring(imgSrc.length-4).toLowerCase().indexOf("png") > -1 
        || img.src.substring(0, 15).toLowerCase().indexOf("image/png") > -1) {

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height );
        var pixDataContainer = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        var pixData = pixDataContainer.data;

        // search for pixel.alpha < 250
        for (var pix = 0, pixDataLen = pixData.length; pix < pixDataLen; pix += 4) {
            if (pixData[pix+3] < 250) {
                texture.imageHasTransparency = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    texture.image = img;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    this.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, false);

}, false );

var fileExtension = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
img.src = "data:image/"+fileExtension+";base64,"+ btoa(imageData.asBinary());
```

The order is correct: first define new Image(), then the onload function and then the source.

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr or jsbin with a sample image?

Comment: Sorry to not have done that. I've figured out the solution, see below. I promise to always set the canvas' size to the image size before i draw something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The image was larger than the canvas, so when context.drawImage() was started, only parts of the area was filled. I've set the canvas dimensions according to the image size, so now it works and we have

```
// ...
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = img.width; // !!!!!
canvas.height = img.height; // !!!!
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height );
var pixDataContainer = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
var pixData = pixDataContainer.data;
// ...
```